# Laravel: files missing with composer once uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I've recently developed a CMS with Laravel and its all working great - on my local machine that is...

When I upload it to my webserver I start getting file not found errors from what I believe is `composer`'s autoloader.

The errors originate from the `require $file` on line 52 (I think, I'm not at the computer right now) in the `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php`.

I'm not familiar with composer at all so I'm not really sure where to start. All I do know is that it works fine on my localhost but doesn't work on my server with the exact same files. I am just lost as to what to try. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run composer install in the server?

Comment: No I didn't but as far as I'm aware,  all I need on the server is the vendor folder. Is that correct? All the files are the same on my local host as they are on the server,  as well as on a portable usb server and it works fine on the usb server and localhost. My usb doesn't have composer installed

Comment: Is it possible the path to your `vendor` folder has changed? I don't _think_ that's the problem, but it could be. @marcanuy's suggestion is the best on - run `composer install` on the server.

Comment: I did check that but its the 4th file being included that has the issue. I noticed that the included file path and the actual file path is exactly the same except for one or two capitalised characters. Including vendor/illuminate rather than vendor/Illuminate for example. The path had changed but I have already made the necessary changes to bootstrap/paths.php. When I get access to my computer again tomorrow I'll see if I can get composer installed On the server r

Comment: It would be really a good idea if you could come back with more detailed information, like the exact error message you are getting, and the exact names of the files that should be included (from the code) and that are present on your server (including differences in capitalization - this probably is important for the server OS, but not your development environment, like Linux vs. Windows).

Comment: I'll come back with more information tomorrow. The 2 servers that are working are windows machines,  and the Web server that is giving me problems runs Linux.

Comment: The linux machine could be an issue if you have used a lot of camel casing throughout your app. Atleast that's what I've heard. Try clearing the entire server folder, and re-syncing your entire app again. Start from scratch and see what happens

Comment: Here are the first errors I get:
    Warning: require(/home/molder/site_files/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/molder/site_files/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 52

    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/molder/site_files/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/molder/site_files/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/molder/site_files/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 52

Comment: The problem with the above is that the correct file path is
    /home/molder/site_files/vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Support/helpers‌​.php - notice the lower case i in illuminate. I have tried just adjusting this include path, and then the actual path of the file so as they both match, but in both cases this error is fixed but there are more and more involving the same issue in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their support. I've got it working now.

I deleted the `vendor` directory, installed composer on the server, updated my files to the ones provided at laravels github, ran `composer install` and finally re-uploaded my config, controllers and views.

This was necessary as `composer update` was giving me even more errors. Either way, I've finally got it working and you guys helped a lot.